# Using Regex To match Binary Strings that have an odd number of 0s and even number of 1s

Tags: python, regex

[Redacted Info]

**Some valid inputs**

- 101
- 10001
- 00011
- 11000
- 0

**Some invalid Inputs**

- 11
- 00
- 10101
- 101101111

EDIT:
For the people suggesting that ReGeX is not the way to go are absolutely correct, but for this question I need to use regex.
Also, My definition of simpler is reducing the number of characters in the regex.(The minimum is about 22 characters long)

Comment: What makes you think it *can* be simplified?

Comment: You have to characterize all of the loops and paths in a finite-state machine, with a string-matching notation ... an inherently messy effort.  Do you have particular evidence that this can and should be reduced?  If not, you're really asking us to do your homework ourselves, and compare answers.

Comment: I don't think regex is the best way for this. Why not just `str.count`?

Comment: @ScottHunter The reason I Know it can be simplified is because my professor said so. He said that this concept can be simplified to about 22 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're determined to do this with regex, then for certain definitions of "simplify", this may fit the bill.

```regex
(?=^0*((10*){2})*?$)(?=^1*(01*)((01*){2})*?$)^.*$

(?=                )                                assert that
   ^              $                                 between the start and end of the string
    0*                                              (consume leading zeros)
      (        )*?                                  there appears as many times as necessary
            {2}                                     two instances of 
       (10*)                                        a 1 followed by any number of 0s
                    (?=^1*     ((01*){2})*?$)       perform the same check as before
                          (01*)                     but require an extra 0 at the start
```

This relies on the `{2}` quantifier to demand a multiple of 2 for the numbers in question, and instead of validating the string all at once, performs 2 checks on the string: the first looks for an even number of 1s, and the second looks for an even number of 0s, plus an extra 0.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qzKAFP/1/)

Comment: Thanks Nick for this Answer! This is definition of simplify I was going for, and thanks to your answer I think I figured out a way to simplify (character wise) it even more!

Comment: @PotatoGod Glad I could help! If you've found a simpler version, please consider posting it as an answer to your own question and accepting it.

Comment: I will definitely do so, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using `Counter` from `collections` is another way to come at it.  It makes it easy to look for odd and even sequences as well as ensuring that the string has only 1s and 0s.

```
from collections import Counter

def is_valid_binary_string(test_string):
    c = Counter(test_string)
    
    # Not valid if anything other than 1s and 0s
    if set(c.keys()) - {"0", "1"}:
        return False
    
    # Valid only if even number of 1s and odd number of 0s
    return c["1"] % 2 == 0 and c["0"] % 2 == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `regex` for this. Its super simple to achieve this using `string.count()` and checking if the response is odd or even.

```
testcases = ['101', '10001', '00011', '11000', '0', '11', '00', '10101', '101101111']
for string in testcases:
    print(string, 'Valid' if string.count('0') % 2 == 1 and string.count('1') % 2 == 0 else 'Invalid')
```

Outputs

```
101 Valid
10001 Valid
00011 Valid
11000 Valid
0 Valid
11 Invalid
00 Invalid
10101 Invalid
101101111 Invalid
```